# How to use one system hash key in multiple systems for facebook login development

Tags: android, facebook, hash

I am using to facebook sdk for facebook login so I know that i need one development machine's hash key and store it into developer.facebook. It is working fine for me in facebook login. But Now i have a case, I have multiple machine such as linux and windows. and all are using in development. so i have to create multiple hash-key and store one by one in developer.facebook. But I am trying a find out a way so that i will use only one machine's hashkey and other machine will be able to use it for facebook login. is it possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to whitelist the debug keystore of one of your machine, and copy it to the other machines. In this way you have the same whitelisted keystore on all machines.

The debug keystore is located in `$HOME/.android/debug.keystore`